# Simulating Static Variables in Scheme

Tags: variables, static, scheme, increment, lexical

A function that returns how many times it has been called in Scheme would look like

```
(define count
  (let ((P 0))
    (lambda () 
      (set! P (+ 1 P))
      P)))

(list (count) (count) (count) (count)) ==> (list 1 2 3 4)
```

But suppose that we have an expression that looks like this

```
(map ______ lst)
```

and we want that to evaluate to

```
(list 1 2 3 ... n)
where n = (length list)
```

The problem requires we use a lambda statement in the blank, and we cannot use any auxiliary definitions like (count) in the blank, so

```
(lambda (x) (count))
```

is not allowed. Simply replacing (count) with the previous definition like this:

```
(map
 (lambda (x)
   ((let ((P 0))
      (lambda () 
        (set! P (+ 1 P))
        P))))
 L)
```

doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very, very close to a correct solution! in the code in the question just do this:

1. The outermost `lambda` is erroneous, delete that line and the corresponding closing parenthesis
2. The innermost `lambda` is the one that will eventually get passed to the `map` procedure, so it needs to receive a parameter (even though it's not actually used)
3. Delete the outermost parenthesis surrounding the `let` form

It all boils down to this: the `lambda` that gets passed to `map` receives a parameter, but also encloses the `P` variable. The `let` form defines `P` only once in the context of the passed `lambda`, and from that point on the `lambda` "remembers" the value of `P`, because for each of the elements in the list the same `P` is used.

Comment: @user1968574 you're welcome! please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 1):

You're 90% of the way there. Use the right-hand-side of your `count` definition in the blank, and add an (ignored) argument to the function.

Comment: If this is what you mean:
(map
 (lambda (x)
   ((let ((P 0))
      (lambda () 
        (set! P (+ 1 P))
        P))))
 L)
I've tried that, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what is meant by "add an ignored argument to the function. Could you clarify a little more please?

Comment: I mean that the (lambda () ...)  in your original code should become (lambda (dontcare) ...).

Answer (score -2):

```
(define add-stat-var
    
    (let ( (P '()) )
        (lambda (x1) 
            (if (equal? x1 "ResetStatVar") (set! P '()) (set! P (cons x1 P)))
        P
        ) ;lambda
      
    ) ;let
      
) ;define

(define (test-add-stat-var x)

    (let* ( (result '()) )
    
            (set! result (add-stat-var 12))
            (set! result (add-stat-var 14))
            (set! result (add-stat-var 16))
            
            (display (add-stat-var x)) (newline)
            
            (set! result (add-stat-var "ResetStatVar"))
            
            (display (cdr (add-stat-var x))) (newline)

    )
    
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please review your posts before and after submitting to ensure that everything looks right.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.